# class httpresponse results in 405 - django

Tags: python, django, class, view, http-status-code-405

I am new to django and I am trying to understand class views.

In urls.py (main) I have:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('webapp.urls')),
]
```

in webapp folder I have:

urls.py (webapp):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from webapp.views import Firstapp

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^whatever$', Firstapp.as_view()),

]
```

views.py (webapp):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse

class Firstapp(View):

    def something(self):
        return HttpResponse('Yes it works!')
```

As I have said, I am trying to use class views and I would appreciate if you could help me understand why class returns 405 error. Thank you. CMD returns 0 problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are subclassing `View` and the only method you define is called `something`.

`View` expects you to define a method for each valid http verb. (GET, POST, HEAD etc). Since `Firstapp` has no such method, `View.dispatch` will return a response with http status 405 (Method not allowed).

> [`dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch)
>
> The view part of the view – the
>   method that accepts a request argument plus arguments, and returns a HTTP response.
>
> The default implementation will inspect the HTTP method and attempt to delegate to a method that matches the HTTP method; a GET will be delegated to get(), a POST to post(), and so on.
>
> By default, a HEAD request will be delegated to get(). If you need to handle HEAD requests in a different way than GET, you can override the head() method. See Supporting other HTTP methods for an example.

To fix this, change your `something` method:

```
def get(self, request):
    return HttpResponse('Yes it works!')
```